# Why does UIView and UIImageView render at different quality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIView and a UIImageView both at 40*40 dimensions. I also have an image at 120*120 and a compressed copy at 40*40 with worse quality.

When I use UIView, in the drawRect: function I have [backgroundImage drawInRect: rect]; It displays two images equally vaguely.

When I use UIImageView, I put imageView.image = backgroundImage; It displays the 120*120 image at a way better quality.

I want to know why is that? What can I do to display the expected quality in the UIView without using a UIImageView?

Comment: A `UIImageView` knows how to handle @2x also.. Which yields a better quality.

Comment: Did you try drawing the 120x120 image in the 40x40 view so it mimics what the image view is doing?

Comment: I tried but the UIView displayed the 120*120 image as vaguely as the 40*40


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   UIImage* myImage = //the higher resolution image
   [myImage drawInRect: rect]; //the 120*120 image does not seem more clear than the 40*40
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Post screenshots. We cannot determine what the problem with an image is, unless we see the image.